# Order of a particular given permutation = LCM(order of all disjoint cycles) ?

Tags: group-theory

If I write (1 3 4 6)(2 3 4)(4 6 1) as a product of disjoint cycles, I get (164)(23), is it true that order of (1 3 4 6)(2 3 4)(4 6 1) is lcm(2,3)=6 (just the order of its disjoint cycles)?

Comment: Write out the definition of what it means for a permutation to have order n and note that disjoint cycles commute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true that the order of a product of disjoint cycles is the least common multiple of the orders of the disjoint cycles in the product.

Comment: @lhf This is not true in general, take an element and its own inverse for example (I know this is old but just in case anybody is reading here from the future)

Comment: @AlexMathers, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Let $\pi \in S$ be a permutation; then write $\pi = S_1 \cdots S_k$ where $S_1, \ldots, S_k \in S$ are disjoint cycles. Define $n_i = \#S_i$ for $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$. Now $\pi^{n_i}$ fixes the elements of $S_i$. So the smallest number which fixes all elements of $\pi$ is $\#\pi = \mathcal{lcm} \{n_1,\ldots,n_k\}$.

Comment: fixates -> fixes

Comment: Oh thx, I haz fixed