# Order of permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Proving that the order of permutations can be written as $ \text{lcm}(n_1,n_2...) $ for $n = \text{order of conjoined cycles}$, I am stuck where it says $ \pi^{n} = \text{identity}$.

Here it is explained in an answer: [Order of a particular given permutation = LCM(order of all disjoint cycles) ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25948/order-of-a-particular-given-permutation-lcmorder-of-all-disjoint-cycles)

I don't get it, though.

Comment: Is my question unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need each cycle to complete an integer number of times.  The first cycle will complete at multiples of $n_1$ times, the second at multiples of $n_2$ times, etc.  You need to find a number that is a multiple of all of these.  The least common multiple will be the smallest.  I suggest you try by hand $n_1=2,n_2=3,n_3=4,n_4=6$ and see what happens.  They all come around together at $LCM(2,3,4,6)=12$